# Why condition enclosed in mutex sections does not deadlock in this golang example?

Tags: go, concurrency

I came across this example on one of the O'Reilly trainings. There is condition that is supposed to prevent widgetInventory become negative. Example works but I don't understand why program does not deadlock when makeSales acquires mutex and widgetInventory is 0.

```
var (
    wg sync.WaitGroup
    mutex = sync.Mutex{}
    widgetInventory int32= 1000
    newPurchase = sync.NewCond(&mutex)
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Starting inventory count = ", widgetInventory)
    wg.Add(2)
    go makeSales()
    go newPurchases()
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("Ending inventory count = ", widgetInventory)
}

func makeSales() {
    for i := 0; i < 3000; i++ {
        mutex.Lock()
        if widgetInventory-100 < 0{
            newPurchase.Wait()
        }
        widgetInventory -= 100
        fmt.Println(widgetInventory)
        mutex.Unlock()
    }
    wg.Done()
}

func newPurchases() {
    for i := 0; i < 3000; i++ {
        mutex.Lock()
        widgetInventory+= 100
        fmt.Println(widgetInventory)
        newPurchase.Signal()
        mutex.Unlock()
    }
    wg.Done()
}
```

I expected code to deadlock when makeSales acquires mutex while widgetInventory is 0.

Comment: The sync.Mutex is not the thing this examples is about, it demonstrates how to use sync.Cond which is "complicated" (please read the documentation and the advice about whether to use sync.Cond). In short: newPurchase.Wait **unlocks** mutex (and locks it again).

Comment: I failed to notice that condition is associated with mutex. Of course source code of Wait reveals all. Code is less readable but whole situation makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: I presume this interplay of the Locker and the Cond makes using sync.Con so error prone or complicated that the official documentation advises against sync.Cond. So it's definitively not an issue on your side.

Comment: One more thing - runtime will detect deadlock if there are no coroutines that can send Signal or Broadcast. Interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I failed to notice that condition is linked to mutex:
`newPurchase = sync.NewCond(&mutex)`
Entering .Wait() unlocks the mutex and tries to acquire it back after condition Signal is received.

condition.Wait() can only be used if mutex is acquired so it works at a cost of code not being as readable as it could be :-)